# Downloading latest stable release of Avidemux?

Tags: windows-xp, open-source, video-editing, video-conversion, avidemux

I would like to try some simple video editing (joining/cutting videos etc.) with Avidemux.

Could you please advise what is the latest release (non-beta version), and where to download it?

The reason I ask - I downloaded **avidemux_2.5_r7200_win32.exe** from the [download page](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/download.html), under "win32 2.5.5 install".  However, when I run the setup it says "Avidemux 2.5.4.7200 (32-bit beta)".

Is this beta version stable to use?  Is there a stable non-beta release I should use instead?

Using Windows XP Home SP 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't tell you how stable that version is but I had a look through the mirror pages and there's a list of release and beta builds [here](http://avidemux.razorbyte.com.au/).  The latest release build according to that site is only a few weeks old.

Comment: I downloaded and installed 2.5.5 (7257) from the link you provided.  The setup did not say beta this time.